# Block USB Devices at login screen, allow all other times

Tags: windows-10, usb

I have been tasked with figuring out why devices on a dock are being blocked before a user logs in. For example, they can not use their mouse or keyboard on the desk, they have to log in using the laptops built in keyboard and mouse.

It turns out the culprit is DMA protection. We want this configured, so I am not willing to just disable this.

Is it true that simply finding a DMA compliant driver for devices like keyboards and mice will allow them to work prior to login?

Also, does anything exist for me to locally mark this device as allowed for testing?

Thank you for any assistance you could provide.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent?  You typically would avoid booting to a USB by locking the firmware settings.  Windows does not have a way to allow a USB device to be connected only after a user is logged in.  Understanding what you are trying to achieve will allow us to write a better answer.

Comment: ok, I was able to do more search on this. Initially, I didn't have any more information than above, however I can confirm the issue was DMA protection. However, this is an important security setting that we do not want to disable. I have been researching, but I do not fully understand what I am reading. Please correct this statement if I am wrong, but am I correct in saying that if I can find DMA compliant drivers, these devices will be allowed through?  Is it possible to mark specific devices as allowed without getting driver updates?

Thank you.

Comment: In modern supported versions of Windows drivers must be signed, if they are not signed, then driver enforcement must be disabled.  As I said Windows doesn’t support devices to be connected only when a user is logged in.  It’s still unclear what you are trying to prevent

Answer (score -2):

And then how to access "advanced startup option" without pressing F8 key.
But you can control (block) usb ports a flash drive non of your.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-enable-usb-port-in-windows-10/

Thank you